# Why does my textbook not define complex square and square root functions at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example, the square function is defined as $w=f(z)=z^2=r^2e^{i2\theta}$, where r>0 and $-\pi<\theta\leq \pi$.  Why is the origin always excluded?  Also, why do we use the branch cut on the negative real axis for the square root function when $f$ is also one-to-one on the the larger $D=\{re^{i\theta}:\text{$r>0 \space and -\pi/2<\theta\leq \pi/2$}\}$?

Comment: The origin need not be excluded, but its excluded often because $\theta$ is undefined for $z=0$.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I am still wondering about the branch cut.

Comment: I don't understand your question about the branch cut for the square root; did you write it wrong?

Comment: I'm defining the square root function as the inverse of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *can* of course define the principal square root function on the negative real axis -- for example by deciding that it will produce a value with positive imaginary part.

In fact one often *does* that.

However, this produces a function *that is not continuous everywhere in its domain* -- some some authors prefer to define it with a slightly smaller domain such that the function *has an open domain* and *is continuous and differentiable everywhere in that domain*.

We could get an everywhere-continuous function just by excluding the *negative* reals, but the domain wouldn't be *open* unless we also exclude the branch point itself. And since most of the theorems in complex analysis are about functions *defined on open domains* (that are differentiable everywhere in their domain) it is convenient to define and name a function of that shape, rather than a slightly-more-defined function that doesn't match the assumptions of our theorems.

Comment: Since $f$ is one-to-one on D we don't need to "decide" what the inverses of f are on the negative x-axis.  For example, the $sqrt{-1=i}$.  But I haven't thought about the issues with continuity, thanks.

Comment: @Michael: The decision may be encoded by whether you take $-\frac\pi2 < \theta \le \frac\pi2$ or $-\frac\pi2 \le\theta < \frac\pi2$ when you select your $D$.

Answer (score 2):

In complex analysis, there's a tension between the notion of function and the notion of multi-valued function.

On the one hand, a lot of the things you work with — like the complex square root — are naturally multi-valued functions. On the other hand, one has a background in studying single-valued functions that one would like to apply, and one tends to look for ways to reduce the study of multi-valued functions to the study of single-valued functions.

Excluding the origin from the domain of the square root is an example of something that makes more sense in the multi-valued picture — the multi-valued square root is *analytic* everywhere except at the origin and at infinity, so that set of points is a good choice of domain.

Although one *could* continuously extend it to $0$ and to $\infty$, the square root has a nasty singularity at both points, so one tends not to do so.

Furthermore (or alternatively, as a reason why the singularity is so nasty), some of our tools for reducing multi-valued functions to single-valued functions simply don't work at $0$ and $\infty$ — for example, for any point $z$, one often likes to have a whole open set $z \in U$ where each "branch" of the multi-valued function can be expressed as an ordinary single-valued function.